# Deserialize JSON to list with unknown object name in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize following JSON.
The problem is that the objects "ANDE" & "DAR" can change.
Means the objects are unknown and change depending on the JSON i wanna deserialize.
About 8000 different objects (ANDE, DAR, ...) need to be deserialized.

```
{"ANDE":
     {"chart":[
     {"date":"20180914","minute":"09:30"},{"date":"20180914","minute":"13:30"}]},
"DAR":
     {"chart":[
     {"date":"20180914","minute":"09:30"},{"date":"20180914","minute":"13:30"}]}}
```

I get the data by HTTP response and want to put into a List:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(API_PATH).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
List historicalDataList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<HistoricalDataResponse>>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The HistoricalDataResponse class looks like:

```
public class HistoricalDataResponse
{
   public string date { get; set; }
   public string minute { get; set; }
}
```

How can i deserialize this kind of JSON with unknown objects in C#?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you known each different pattern use a json.net TypeConverter https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: I updated my answer, please see

Comment: Did you try to deserialize to a dictionary ? `Dictionary<string, xxx>`

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use a dynamic variable:

```
dynamic ReturnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
```

note that as in dynamic objects, properties are determined after being assigned in runtime, so you will not get a drop down menu in design time, and also as its properties are unknown in design time, and property you test in design time even if its not correct, you wont get an error, and you will get the error in runtime when it is assigned.

```
    dynamic ReturnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

try
{
      var a = ReturnValue.ANDE; // will work if it has ANDE property.
      // do what you would do with ANDE
}
catch{}
try
{
      var a = ReturnValue.DAR; // will work if it has DAR property.
      // do what you would do with DAR
}
catch{}
```

Comment: I cant put ANDE in my running code as i wont know if "ANDE" is in the JSON.  
Maybe instead of "ANDE" there is "DCUD" or something else

Comment: There are about 8000 different types possible.  So its not possible to put it into code. It needs to deserialize whatever object is in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary with string as key type :

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("url").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DateResponse>>(json);     
    foreach (var element in result)
    {
        var key = element.Key; // ANDE
        foreach (var item in element.Value.Chart)
        {
            var date = item.date;
            var minute = item.minute;
        }
    }
}


public class DateResponse{
    public List<HistoricalDataResponse> Chart { get; set; }
}

public class HistoricalDataResponse
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string minute { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i also need the ticker "ANDE" and "DAR" in the result.  
Otherwise i dont know which DataResponse is linked to which ticker. 
 
And how can i feed the DeserializeObject with the response.Content from the API?  
`HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(IEXTrading_API_PATH).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: `DeserializeObject` is like your `ReadAsAsync`. I used it for simplicity in the repro. If you need all data, just remove Select and SelectMany lines. The tickers will be the key in the dictionary

Comment: The line with the DeserializeObject works but the code line `var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<string, DateResponse>>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` does not feed my result.

Comment: can you try with ReadAsStringAsync and then DeserializeObject ?